# -bash: pscp: command not found

Tags: linux, unix, putty, pscp

```
pscp cis249.hacc.edu ./dgf1928_archive_backup.tar c:\users\mrmet_000\desktop\Cis249.hacc.edu archive backup
```

The above syntax does nothing because pscp will not work on my windows 8.1 system for some reason. Does anyone have any clue what I must do to allow this to work?

Comment: "my cup is empty. what do I need to do to get a drink from the cup?" if pscp isn't working, then use some other app that does scp...

Comment: Well I'm thinking it's not windows 8, but rather something with the path of my putty files.

Comment: if it's path-related, then use the absolute path to pscp.exe, e.g. `c:\users\johndoe\downloads\pscp`

Comment: Also, I'm using putty, so pscp is the most viable option.

Comment: "will not work ... for some reason" is extremely vague.... Specifying exactly how it "will not work", or the exact "some reason" for such would allow people a much better chance to understand what is going on, with the possibility of generating more useful answers as a result...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to put the pscp file in the same directory that you working in and type:

.\pscp file targetuser@targetserver:.

Pscp just used strings to represent user@host:file. The position is the source and the second is the target.

This will ask for a password and copy to the home directory of targetuser on targetserver. For more advanced stuff like login with no password, set up ssh keys through putty and reference that name.  Here is what I think you should type (from the directory where pscp is):

.\pscp c:\users\mrmet_000\desktop\dgf1928_archive_backup.tar $USER@cis249.hacc.edu.